# power query (powerbi) data structure: creating a crosssection-temporal data structure (panel data)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am working in powerbi and I have a problem in the power query editor. My source table contains cross-sectional data with a primary key.

```
primary_key  data_feature_A
    1             A
    2             B
    3             A
    4             C
```

I would like to efficiently transform my data into the following structure:

```
primary_key_1   time_year  data_feature_A
    1             2019         A
    1             2020         A
    1             2021         A
    1             2022         A
    2             2019         B
    2             2020         B
    2             2021         B
    2             2022         B
    3             2019         A
    3             2020         A
    3             2021         A
    3             2022         A
    4             2019         C
    4             2020         C
    4             2021         C
    4             2022         C
```

I would like to run such a procedure on a very big data set (original data). Each row at the end of the procedure should have as its identifiers both a cross-sectional identifier and a time marker (year).

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you run into problems?  How are you determining which years to use?

Comment: Oh, and does your actual data set have only the two columns, and only three columns in the results?

Comment: No, I have 300 crosssectional items and 22 years. The items are determined from a particular odbc source.

Comment: How many **Columns** in data and results? If more than 2/3, please give example

Comment: Also please show your code for what you have tried.

Comment: My original data are 300 crossesectional items, taken from a odbc input source. the input source contains 300 rows with a primary key and various feature columns. My goal is a table with 6000 (=300*22) rows with two columns. The first column will be the (cross section) item identifiers and the second column will contain the year identifier. (After this step I would like to add additional columns through merge query using these two columns (cross section and year) as identifiers for importing data from other sources.)

Comment: I have no clue how to tackle this problem. I have no code at all so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a PowerQuery that expands all the rows with years from 2019 to current year + 1:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUXJUitWJVjICspzALGMgyxnMMgGyXJRiYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [primary_key = _t, data_feature_a = _t]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "time_year", each List.Numbers(2019, Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow() ) + 2 - 2019)),
    #"Expanded time_year" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "time_year")
in
    #"Expanded time_year"
```

Answer (score 0):

I appended my table multiple times to itself through in power query using the SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table
```

In the next step, I added an index column (starting with 0). Then in a final step, I added a custom column with the formula

```
2019+Number.Round([Index]/(List.Max(#"table"[Index])+1)/4,0)
```

This yields the time_year column.